# ErrorListPlot with a different color for each element of the list

Tags: plotting, style

I would like to plot a list with ErrorListPlot but each dot with a different color like the example in the ListPlot's documentation :

```
ListPlot[Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi,Pi/20}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

I have some trouble to adapt this for ErroListPlot. Is there a similar way to do it ?

edit :

here my list of data :

```
data =  {{{100, 190.643}, ErrorBar[1.07807]}, {{200, 187.951}, ErrorBar[1.13827]}, {{400, 186.07},   ErrorBar[1.28594]}, {{800, 183.452},   ErrorBar[1.63607]}, {{1600, 181.18}, ErrorBar[2.53651]}}
```

I tried to color (with different color) each {{x, y}, ErrorBar[err]} , just the {x,y} and just the y but none of these options worked.

Comment: If you would give an example of your data (with the errors) to play with...

Comment: Done. Thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** In versions 12.+, you can use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) to create a new data set that can be used with `ListPlot` to get the desired picture without the need for `ErrorListPlot`:

```
data2 = data /. {{a_, b_}, ErrorBar[c_]} :> {{a, Around[b, c]}};

ListPlot[data2, IntervalMarkersStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can wrap each data element with `List`:

```
ErrorListPlot[List /@ data]
```

[image]